# Validation Rule to make Notes required

Tags: validation-rule, required-field

I am trying to create a validation rule where if Stage is Closed Lost or Cancelled the Notes field is required.  I am having problems with the formula.

Comment: Do you mean a field on Opportunity named "Notes" or are you trying to require something in the Notes & Attachments related list if the stage is closed?

Comment: What problems are you having? What do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

That should be very straight forward, try below expression, make sure the field names are correct.

```
(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Closed Lost") || ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Cancelled")) && ISBLANK(Notes__c)
```